# Get DescriptionAttribute from enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum which I use to find a coordinating string value. One of these enums has a space in it which I'm thus trying to use the description attribute to find that value. I'm having trouble casting back to the public class after it finds the DescriptionAttribute.

```
public class Address
{
   ...blah...more class datatypes here...

    public AddressType Type { get; set; }

    ...blah....
```

}

```
public enum AddressType
{
    FRA = 0,
    JAP = 1,
    MEX = 2,
    CAN = 3,
    [Description("United States")]
    UnitedStates = 4, 

}


 if (Address.Type.ToString() == "UnitedStates")
            {
               Adddress.Type = GetDescription(Address.Type);
            }

private static AddressType GetDescription(AddressType addrType)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = addrType.GetType().GetField(addrType.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : addrType.ToString();            
    }
```

Within the GetDescription method how do I cast it back to its public class data type 'AddressType' it fails because here its a string?

Comment: The enum is `AddrType` but your passing your method a parameter of type `AddressType`. You're also attempting to return a `string`, when the return type of your method is `AddressType`.

Comment: sorry should of mentioned the enum is a part of a another public class see above.

Comment: You're still going to have issues (at least given the code you've posted) because the type names do not match (`AddressType` vs `AddrType`) and the return type of the method you provided is not `string`.

Comment: thats what I'm having trouble with is the string. I need to cast it back to AddressType, addrType is just the local name I believe.

Comment: So you want to pass an `AddressType` into the method to get the `string` description, and then convert it back to the original `AddressType`? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to directly cast a string to an enum. You will need to write a converter method that takes a string and returns the enum.

Simple Example but you could use a dictionary and make it its own class.

```
//string values are case sensitive
    private AddressType StringToEnum(string enumString)
            {
                AddressType returnValue;
                switch (enumString)
                {
                    case "United States":
                        returnValue = AddressType.UnitedStates;
                        break;
                    case "France":
                        returnValue = AddressType.FRA;
                        break;
                    case "Japan":
                        returnValue = AddressType.JAP;
                        break;
                    case "Mexico":
                        returnValue = AddressType.MEX;
                        break;
                    case "Canada":
                        returnValue = AddressType.CAN;
                        break;
                    default:
                        returnValue = AddressType.UnitedStates;
                        break;

                }
                return returnValue;
            }
```

if you are looking to convert a string to an enum you will need to do something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I not 100% sure what you're asking for, but the following method returns the `string` description or name of provided `AddressType`.

```
private static string GetDescription(AddressType addrType)
{
    FieldInfo fi = addrType.GetType().GetField(addrType.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = 
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : addrType.ToString();            
}
```

Notice the return type `string`.

Comment: yes and where I'm having trouble is I'm looking to return it as AddressTpye because it is a part of my class which is an enum

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a helper method to remove the spaces from the sting and find the correct Enum

Example:

```
public T EnumFromString<T>(string value) where T : struct
{
    string noSpace = value.Replace(" ", "");
    if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Any(x => x.ToString().Equals(noSpace)))
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), noSpace);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
    public enum Test
    {
        UnitedStates,
        NewZealand
    }

    Test MyEnum = EnumFromString<Test>("New Zealand"); // Returns 'NewZealand'
```